# Convert an random generated PIN to Secure String

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

i am creating a Powershell script to enable Bitlocker. For this i need a PIN which is converted to a securestring. This PIN must be randomly generated. For this i have these two options:

```
$pin = Get-Random -Minimum 0 - Maximum 9
```

and

```
$pin = ( (1..6) | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 9 } ) -join ''
```

The first one has a problem for my usage because it generates some PINs with 5 characters but i need 6 characters for my usage

The second one does the right job for now.

As already said i need a secure-string to enable bitlocker. I've tried the *ConvertTo-SecureString* cmdlet

```
ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pin -Force
```

I get the error which says:

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is NULL.

Does someone knows how to make it work?

Btw: I am beginner with Powershell

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Did you make sure to run the pin-generation code before `ConvertTo-SecureString`?

Comment: [⚠️ **Important**](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0#securestring-operations)
A **SecureString** object should never be constructed from a **String**, because the sensitive data is already subject to the memory persistence consequences of the immutable **String** class. The best way to construct a **SecureString** object is from a character-at-a-time unmanaged source, such as the **Console.ReadKey** method.

Comment: This means that you actually shouldn't use `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pin -Force` but something like: `$SecurePin.AppendChar($Char)` as in this [`New-Password`](https://github.com/iRon7/New-Password/blob/main/New-Password.ps1d) script: `New-Password -Length 6 -Upper -1 -Lower -1 -Symbols -1`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the problem was i used the cmdled on the wrong place. After i generated the Pin i piped it to a file which was saved on a specified path. After that Out-File cmdled i piped it again with ConvertTo-Securestring. 

It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You are able to pipe following command:

```
$pin = ( (1..6) | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 9 } ) -join ''
```

For example:

```
$pin = ( (1..6) | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 9 } ) -join '' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a `SecureString` object and append the numbers to it one at a time, which is what the aforementioned [New-Password script](https://github.com/iRon7/New-Password/blob/main/New-Password.ps1) does:

```
$pin= [SecureString]::new()

(Get-Random (0..9) -Count 6).ForEach{ $pin.AppendChar($_) }
```

If you want to include letters:

```
# PowerShell 5.1 compliant
(48..122 -as 'char[]' -match '[0-9a-z]' | Get-Random -Count 6).ForEach{ $pin.AppendChar($_) }
### OR ###
([char[]](48..122) -match '[0-9a-z]' | Get-Random -Count 6).ForEach{ $pin.AppendChar($_) }

# Simpler alternative for newer versions:
(Get-Random ('0'..'9' + 'A'..'Z' + 'a'..'z') -Count 6).ForEach{ $pin.AppendChar($_) }
```

---